# Tooltip for options_from_collection_for_select on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of values showing in the dropdown. In the dropdown some of the text values are very lengthy, so am unable to view them completely. So i want to use a tooltip here, hence i can able to hover on the option then the complete value is shown.

Code is given below:

```
<%= select_tag(:book_id,
          options_from_collection_for_select(@books, :id, :name),
                     multiple: true, id: 'book_id') %>
```

Can someone help me here !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please follow the following link it may helps you.

http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/how-to-set-tooltip-for-dropdownlist-t561.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solution to render tooltip on select tag options:

```
<%= f.select :compliance_tier, options_for_select(User.roles.map {|k, v| [k.humanize.capitalize, k,{'data-toggle'=> 'tooltip', title: method_to_render_text(k)}]}, f.object.role, {},class: 'form-control w-100 font-12 h-auto py-2 shadow-none pr-4', required: true, id: :user_role %>
```